# When creating an instance of a struct, do I have to send in arguments for all the property parameters initialized in the init() method?

Tags: swift, struct, parameters, arguments, instance

//When creating an instance of this struct, do I have to send in arguments for all the property parameters initialized in the init() method?

//the compiler isn't allowing me to send an only an argument for rate, but also it wants me to send in an argument for "carQuickness".....what if i had many properties initialized, and i don't want to use all of them when creating an instance of a struct, or class, or enum...??? I'm confused.....

```
struct milesPerHour {

var rate : Double

var carQuickness : Bool

init(_ rates: Double,  quickness: Bool){

    self.rate = rates
    self.carQuickness = quickness
    }

}

let MPH = milesPerHour (50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom initializer:

```
struct MilesPerHour {
    let rate = 1.0
    let carQuickness : Bool

    init(quickness: Bool) {
        self.carQuickness = quickness
    }

}

let MPH = MilesPerHour(quickness: true)
```